# Android Studio problemas al compartir mp3

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Este es mi codigo:

```
peroperoperopero.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
@Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Intent compartirAudio = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            compartirAudio.setType("com.whatsapp");
            compartirAudio.setType("audio/mp3");
            compartirAudio.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                    Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.lucas.botoneradeteloresumoasinomas/" + R.raw.peroperopero));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(compartirAudio, "Compartir vía"));
            return false;
        }
    });
```

mantengo precionado el boton me sale el menu para compartir, lo comparto en un grupo de WhatsApp y se envia un archivo de tipo documento que pesa 50kb y que no se puede abrir con nada, que tengo que cambiar o agregar para que funcione? muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Hola tu problema es que el archivo de audio no es accesible por whatsapp ya que pertenece a tu aplicacion. Lo que deberias hacer es usar un FileProvider que justamente sirve para poder compartir archivos entre aplicaciones.

En el manifest deberas poner esto dentro del tag application

```
<application>
   <provider
      android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
      android:authorities="com.example.lucas.botoneradeteloresumoasinomas.fileprovider"
      android:grantUriPermissions="true"
      android:exported="false">
      <meta-data
         android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
         android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
   </provider>
</application>
```

En deberas crear el archivo `filepaths.xml` en el directorio `res/xml/` adentro tendras que poner algo asi:

```
<paths>
   <files-path path="music/" name="mymusic"/>
</paths>
```

Finalmente para conseguir la URI solo deberas usar el metodo `getUriForFile` que te provee FileProvider y usar esa URI para compartir el archivo.

```
File myFile = new File("res/raw/peroperopero");
Uri newUri = getUriForFile(getContext(), "com.example.myapp.fileprovider", myFile);
```

Con esta uri deberias poder compartir el archivo tal como lo estabas intentando

```
File myFile = new File("res/raw/peroperopero");
Uri newUri = getUriForFile(getContext(), "com.example.lucas.botoneradeteloresumoasinomas.fileprovider", myFile);
Intent compartirAudio = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
compartirAudio.setType("com.whatsapp");
compartirAudio.setType("audio/mp3");
compartirAudio.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,newUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(compartirAudio, "Compartir vía"));
```

Te dejo un link con una explicacion mas detallada de como [compartir archivos usando file provider](https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/share-files-using-fileprovider) ademas de la [documentacion de FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider)

Comment: Hola Erick como andas? gracias por responder disculpa que no lo había visto! sabes que hice todo lo que dijiste pero tuve un problema con el getContext() lo cambie y cuando pruebo la app y quiero compartir se detiene la app, debe haber algo mal en el codigo que escribi, yo no entiendo mucho, podras decirme que esta mal, este es el codigo:

Comment: No se entiende si lo escribo aqui, asi que voy a escribirlo como si respondiera a la pregunta.

Comment: Ahi lo edite para que quede mucho mas claro

Answer (score 0):

```
peroperoperopero.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Intent compartirAudio = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            compartirAudio.setType("com.whatsapp");
            compartirAudio.setType("audio/mp3");
            compartirAudio.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                    Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.lucas.botoneradeteloresumoasinomas/" + R.raw.peroperopero));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(compartirAudio, "Compartir vía"));
            File myFile = new File("res/raw/peroperopero");
            Uri newUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), "com.example.myapp.fileprovider", myFile);
            return false;
```

Comment: Ya me imagino que no va a funcionar porque estas compartiendo lo mismo que antes, tenes que compartir la newUri ademas de remplazar com.example.myapp por lo que corresponda, com.example.lucas.botoneradeteloresumoasinomas me imagino.

Comment: Muchas gracias! lo pegue pero el metodo getUriForFile me lo marca en rojo y me da 4 opciones:

Comment: 1) Crear un metodo 'getUriForFile'
2) Import static method
3) Qualify static call
4) Rename Reference

Comment: Le puse la 2) Import static method pero ahora 'getContext' se me puso rojo!

Comment: me da 4 opciones también:
1) Expand static import
2) Split intro declaration
3) Add method contract
4) Anotate method 'getContext'

Comment: Es un ejemplo, remplaza lo que haga falta, por ejemplo getContext() es para obtener contexto, yo no se si lo llamas desde un servicio, un Activity, un Fragment o una libreria, vos pasale el cotexto que tengas.

Comment: No tengo idea cual es el contexto que tengo, por que no tengo idea de como programar, fui logrando cosas a base de preguntas y tutoriales de YouTube! Si me puedes decir cual es o donde estaría o que poner te lo agradecería un montón!

Comment: proba con MiActivity.this quizas ese sea tu contexto, obviamente remplaza MiActivity por el nombre de tu Activity que yo no se como se llama, tampoco se si esta en un activity, para eso tendria que ver el resto del codigo